# Hide UISearchBar under UINavigationBar when ending search

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I don't want the `UISearchBar` to be visible for the user unless the search-button to the right is pressed.

[image]

I have no problem to toggle the `UISearchBar`. I do that with the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Hide searchBar
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
}

- (IBAction)toggleSearchbar:(id)sender{
    NSTimeInterval delay;
    if(self.tableView.contentOffset.y > 1000){
        delay = 0.4;
    } else{
        delay = 0.1;
    }
    [self performSelector:@selector(activateSearch) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay];
}

- (void)activateSearch{
    [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0) animated:NO];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

That pushes the `UINavigationBar` up and shows the `UISearchBar`. My problem is when ending the search. I then want the reversed effect. The `UINavigationBar` should come down from the top and cover the `UISearchBar` again. Now the `UINavigationBar` comes down from the top and pushes the `UISearchBar` down with it. I want the `UISearchBar` to stay at the top so that the `UINavigationBar` covers it when coming down.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `UISearchDisplayController`, you can override `searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:` method of `UISearchDisplayDelegate`. Or you can override `searchBarSearchButtonClicked:` method of `UISearchBarDelegate` class.

Comment: Yes I use `UISearchDisplayController`. I've tried to do `[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];`in `searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:`but that first takes down the `UINavigationBar` and the `UISearchBar` and when that's done the `UISearchBar`is animated back up. I don't want the `UISearchBar` to be animated down with the `UINavigationBar`.